# How to automatically measure\monitor the average of sums of a consecutive samplers in jmeter?

Tags: monitoring, jmeter

I have the following JMeter test plan.

```
+Test Plan
   +Login Thread Group
      HttpRequest1
      HttpRequest2
      HttpRequest3
```

Is there a way to automatically view\monitor the average of sums of HttpRequest1 ,2 and 3?
I couln't found a way to do it in "Summary Report" or "Aggregate Report"

Is it possible? or do I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you explicitly mean 'the average of sums' As in the average of the total sum for each request over the duration of the test run? If so, then I'm not aware of any JMeter listeners will show you the sum of elapsed time for a sampler, it's not something typically required. Instead, you could probably get what you need fairly easily from reading the jtl file at the command line.

But perhaps you meant something else, you might find that using a [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) serves you requirements. This will record and show the total elapsed time for multiple requests. So in your example, you might wrap HTTPRequest1, 2 & 3 in a transaction controller and this would give you the sum of all three requests. Then, the Aggregate and Summary listeners would show you the average for this transaction as a separate line.

Comment: Thanks you Oliver! "Transaction Controller" is prefect for my case (: